# How can I use template metaprogramming to transform arguments and fold them into function arguments?

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, variadic-templates, template-meta-programming

I have written a pseudocode and I am trying to convert it to use variadic templates for my usecase:

```cpp
template<A>
struct Pool {
  std::vector<A> components;
  std::vector<size_t> entityIndices;
  std::vector<uint32_t> entities;
}

std::tuple<ComponentPools...> pools;

template <class A, class B, class C>
void iterate(const std::function<void (uint32_t, const A &, const B &, const C &)> &iterFn) {
  auto &smallestPool = getSmallestPool<A, B, C>(pools);
  auto &poolA = std::get<Pool<A>>(pools).components;
  auto &poolB = std::get<Pool<B>>(pools).components;
  auto &poolC = std::get<Pool<C>>(pools).components;

  for (size_t i = 0; i < smallestPool.entities.size(); ++i) {
    if (!entityHasComponents<A, B, C>(smallestPool.entities[i])) continue;

    A a = poolA.components[poolA.entityIndices[i]];
    B b = poolB.components[poolB.entityIndices[i]];
    C c = poolC.components[poolC.entityIndices[i]];

    iterFn(smallestPool.entities[i], a, b, c);
  }
}
```

What is the right approach to achieve this? I have been playing around with c++17 fold but did not get anywhere.

EDIT: Here is what I want to achieve (code not working because I don't know how to access variadic arguments in a linear, non-recursive way):

```cpp
template <class... PickedComponents>
void iterate(const std::function<void (uint32_t, const PickComponents &...)> &iterFn) {

 // components
 std::tuple<std::vector<PickComponents>&...> components = std::get<Pool<PickComponents>...>(pools).components;

 // indices
 std::tuple<std::vector<size_t>&...> entityIndices = std::get<Pool<PickComponents>...>(pools).entityIndices;

 // entities
 std::tuple<std::vector<uint32_t>&...> entities = std::get<Pool<PickComponents>...>(pools).entityIndices;


 for (size_t i = 0; i < 1000; +i) {
   auto &firstEntityVector = std::get<0>(entities);
   if (!entityHasComponents<PickComponents...>(firstEntityVector[i])) {
     continue;
   }

   std::tuple<PickComponents...> values = components[entityIndices[i]];
   iterFn(firstEntityVector[i], values...);
 }
}
```

Comment: There's a lot of different missing pieces to this puzzle, some implied, some less so. Which part of this is causing you trouble?

Comment: Since this is supposed to be pseudo code, please show some real "input" (so to speak) and what you want as a real result in form of instantiations etc.

Comment: Are you trying to use the parameter pack for the `std::function` parameter?

Comment: I added a code snippet that I am trying to make it so it compiles but so far I have been having no luck. Sorry about the lack of clarity. I don't know how to write any metaprogramming code that is not recursive; so, I am stuck with too many parts of the code not working.

Comment: I have found the answer to my question. The main was that I didn't know how variadic template "packing" (I think that's what the "..." stands for when not doing the fold syntax) worked but once I understood it, it was fairly straightforward to solve this issue.